# How do I self-study String Theory?

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I am an absolute beginner, with little to no knowledge on the subject but I have somehow developed a strong interest in theories like String theory and M-theory, by reading about them on other forums. So can you   recommend me any farily accessible books or other materials that could help me understand these theories in-depth? Or do I have to extensively study other areas in physics before I am able to comprehend them, if so, what are those other topics?

Comment: What is your level of physics knowledge?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29007/2451

Answer (score 1):

String theory is not an easy theory, and there's a reason it's not usually taught at undergraduate level. But if you really want to learn more about it, as far as I know, [this is the standard textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521880327): *A First Course in String Theory* by Barton Zwiebach.

Comment: String theory is not a theory. It is a framework in which you build theories. Just like QFT is not a theory, the standard model is.