# Why is the proper time $\tau$ the only invariant under diffomorphizem?

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, path-integral, quantum-gravity, diffeomorphism-invariance

I'm following Witten's essay: [What Every Physicist Should Know About String Theory](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/PT.3.2980)
. When applying path integral in 1D Witten mention:

> Part of the process of evaluating the path integral in our quantum gravity model is to integrate over the metric on the one-manifold, modulo diffeomorphisms. But up to diffeomorphism, the one-manifold has only one invariant, its total length τ, which we will interpret as the elapsed proper time.

So my question is why this is true:

1. Why is the proper time $\tau$ invariant?
2. Why is it the the only invariant?

Comment: In the point particle theory, you would expect your physical quantities to *not* depend on how you parameterise the points on the worldline of the particle, hence $\tau$ (the worldline's length) is diffeomorphism invariant. As for why it is the *only* invariant, 1D is not that interesting, is it that surprising that it has minimal symmetries?

Comment: I think that I am confused because the dimensions. What does he mean when he say 1 dimension - (1+1) manifold?

Comment: @ziv (1+1)-dimensions means one temporal dimension and one spatial dimension.

Comment: @J.Murray Yes I know. I'm asking if Witten refer to (1+1) manifold or 1 manifold

Comment: Oh, I see.  Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  Witten is referring to a 1+0-dimensional spacetime.

Comment: @J.Murray So this dimension is purely spatial or is it 1 dimensional manifold that  embedded in some way in (1+3) manifold?